# Angular user data coming as [object object]

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a login service with discord Oauth2.

After the user authorize discord, they are redirected to home page.

my login service is like this:

```
login() {
this.commonService.showLoadingOverlay();
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/auth/login/').subscribe((data: any) => {
  const token = data.token;
  this.token = token;
  if (token) {
    this.userInfo = data.user;
    console.log(this.userInfo);
    this.userId = data.user.user_id;
    this.discordId = data.user.discord_id;
    this.authStatusListener.next(true);
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    const expiresInDuration = data.expiresIn;
    const now = new Date();
    const expirationDate = new Date(now.getTime() + expiresInDuration * 1000);
    this.saveAuthData(token, expirationDate, this.userId, this.userInfo);
    this.setAuthTimer(expiresInDuration);

    this.commonService.hideLoadingOverlay();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}, error => {
  this.commonService.hideLoadingOverlay();
  this.router.navigate(['/'])
  const message = 'Not logged in...'
  this.commonService.showErrorMessage(message);
}

)
  }
```

Following a guide I was told to add this to save in local storage:

```
 private getAuthData() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const expirationDate = localStorage.getItem("expiration");
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
    const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    if (!token || !expirationDate) {
      return;
    }
    return {
      token: token,
      expirationDate: new Date(expirationDate),
      userId: userId,
      userInfo: userInfo
    }
  }

     autoAuthUser() {
    const authInformation = this.getAuthData();
    if (!authInformation) {
      return;
    }
    const now = new Date();
    const expiresIn = authInformation.expirationDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (expiresIn > 0) {
      this.token = authInformation.token;
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.userId = authInformation.userId;
      this.userInfo = authInformation.userInfo;
      this.setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
    }
  }
```

I also have this to get the user info:

```
getUserInfo() {
    return this.userInfo;
  }

getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
  }
```

in my sidenav component I am calling user info like this:

```
if(this.currentUser) {
  this.userId = this.authService.getUserId();
  console.log(this.userId);
  this.userInfo = this.authService.getUserInfo();
  console.log('user:')
  console.log(this.userInfo);
}
```

user ID is comming fine, but the user info object is coming as [Object Object], I have also tried to console.log userInfo.user_id

the data should be like this:

```
{user_id: "13", discord_id: "123456xxxx", username: null}
```

any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in `console.log(this.userInfo);` and check the type? Set a breakpoint in `this.userInfo = data.user;` and check the value.

Comment: You should find a network monitor in your browser. There you should find a request to `http://localhost:3000/auth/login/`. What is the response?

Comment: @ThomasSablik when I console.log inside the service, the data is displaying just fine. But in the sidenav component when I call getUserInfo(); it's coming as Object Object

Comment: What's the type of `this.userInfo` in the sidenav component?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am declaring it as userInfo = null

Comment: Have you checked the type in the debugger?

Comment: @ThomasSablik in debugger it's userInfo: "[object Object]" if this is what you mean

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify(this.userInfo)`?

Comment: @StPaulis Can you explain why this would be necessary?

Comment: I think `const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");` is the problem. You tried to write an actual object into local storage. That doesn't work. You have to stringify the object before you write it.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes I tried JSON, didn't work. I have updated my question and added to extra methods getAuthData and autoAuthuser(). I think the issue is here

Comment: Cause maybe the value is unsuitable to print, maybe (I have seen this on VSCode on mac) there is a problem with console.log('user:') in the previous line. 

Can you please try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write an actual object into local storage with `localStorage.setItem` and read it with `localStorage.getItem`. You have to stringify before you write it there and parse after you read it.

The result of writing an actual object into local storage with `localStorage.setItem` is that the string `"[object Object]"` is stored instead of the object. In

```
const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
```

you are reading the string from local storage and writing it into `userInfo`.

You should

```
const userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"));
```

and

```
const userInfo = {user_id: "13", discord_id: "123456xxxx", username: null};
localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
```

You can see the problem when you open the local storage in your browser and check the value for `userInfo`. It's not

```
{user_id: "13", discord_id: "123456xxxx", username: null}
```

but

```
[object Object]
```